# How to hide button with button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index page and I put button_to on each line. The task of the button is to send the "username" content in the row to another table. I want the button to be hidden after doing this, I want it to be visible again when it is deleted from the table.

I did the process of sending the data, but I was unable to hide the button.

```
#rad_accts_controller
def create
  @rad_acct = Banlist.new(rad_acct_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @rad_acct.save
      format.html { redirect_to @rad_acct, notice: 'Banlist was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rad_acct }
      format.js { redirect_to rad_accts_url }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @rad_acct.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js { redirect_to rad_accts_url }
    end
  end
end

 def rad_acct_params
    params.permit(:username)
 end 



#rad_acct view index.html.erb
<% @rad_accts.each do |rad_acct| %>
   <tr class="gradeX">
    <td><%= rad_acct.username %></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'Ban', {:controller => "rad_accts", :action => "create", :username => rad_acct.username } , :method=>:post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true  %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

When I press the button, the user name in the rad_accts table is copied to the banlist table. However, the button for the transferred username on the rad_acct index page does not disappear.

When I delete the corresponding username from the banlist index page, the button on the rad_acct index page should be visible

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using remote:true in the button. This means that the call is made via javascript. This also means that any change to the UI, should also be handled through Javascript. You could add an onclick handler to the button, assuming you use jQuery:

```
$('button#id-of-button').on('click', function() {
   $(this).hide()
})
```

But this is only the first step, as a reload would cause the button to show again. So you need to make the button conditional in your view as well. As I do not know what attributes you use, I use meta:

```
#rad_acct view index.html.erb
<% @rad_accts.each do |rad_acct| %>
   <tr class="gradeX">
    <td><%= rad_acct.username %></td>
    <td>
      <% if rad_acct.user_not_banned? %>
        <%= button_to 'Ban', {:controller => "rad_accts", :action => "create", :username => rad_acct.username } , :method=>:post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true  %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I really couldn't express it.

In fact, the user is not a user of devis. I have a model named banlist and I have a column named username here.

The username in the rad_acct model sends the banlist table when I click the ban button on the index page.

@rad_acct = Banlist.new (rad_acct_params)

The button of the row id sent after sending must be hidden.

If banlist.username == rad_acct.username rad_acct.username id button hide

I am using Javascript. It was a right approach.

Answer (score 0):

the css class active should work.

```
.button:active {
   display: none;
}
```

The active class refers to a link or  tag which has already been clicked. Then adding display:none; to a class should make the content inside invisible.